# Mass-assignment on collection

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have the following models:

```
class EventParticipant < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :event
has_one :user

attr_accessible :name, :email, :is_organizer, :is_attending
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :event_participants

attr_accessible :event_participants_attributes

accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_participants
end

class HappyHour < Event
end
```

And their corresponding schemas:

```
create_table "event_participants", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.boolean  "is_organizer"
    t.boolean  "is_attending"
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "events", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.boolean  "is_finalized"
    t.string   "type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
add_foreign_key "event_participants", "events", :name => "event_participants_events_fk"
```

Now, on the EventParticipantsController controller I load the HappyHour model from the request like this:

```
@happy_hour = HappyHour.new(params[:happy_hour])
```

But for some reason the mass-assignment on HappyHour's event_participants attribute fails:

> Started POST "/event_participants" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-25 18:55:31 -0300
>     Processing by EventParticipantsController#create as JS
>     Parameters: {"happy_hour"=>{"event_participants"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Diego", "email"=>"XXX@YYY.com", "is_organizer"=>"true"}, "1"=>{"name"=>"Test", "email"=>"test@email.com", "is_organizer"=>"false"}}}, "add_event_participant"=>"aaa@bbb.com"}
>   WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: event_participants

What am I missing? I have found plenty of examples on mass-assignment to related objects on one-to-one relationships but none with one-to-many as is my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `event_participants`, you should be submitting `event_participants_attributes`.

You can also check out the Railscasts on nested model forms. They're dealing with one-to-many relationships. Here's [part one](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [part two](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2). They're pretty old, and the javascript parts are a bit out of date, but he basic gist is still correct.